# How do I make a UNUserNotification that's consistent through app states?

Tags: ios, swift

I make a UNUserNotification like this:

```
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "a title"
    content.body = "a body"
    content.sound = .default

    content.categoryIdentifier = "\(type(of: self))"

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(
        identifier: UUID().uuidString,
        content: content,
        trigger: UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0.01, repeats: false)
    )

    let category = UNNotificationCategory(
        identifier: content.categoryIdentifier,
        actions: [
            UNNotificationAction(identifier: Strings.accept.id, title: Strings.accept.title, options: [.authenticationRequired, .foreground]),
            UNNotificationAction(identifier: Strings.reject.id, title: Strings.reject.title, options: [.authenticationRequired, .destructive])
        ],
        intentIdentifiers: [],
        options: .customDismissAction
    )
```

It will show a notification with a title and body, and two custom action buttons (accept and reject, it's an incoming call). It plays a sound too, but for some reason not if the app is foregrounded.
I also try to fake a persistent notification with it, like the way Whatsapp does it by repeating a local notification every ~4 seconds, but the second time it shows the notification the sound is cut off a bit. It's not the sound of the first one, the second one shows with its own sound playing but this time it doesn't fully play out. The sound is only ~1-2 seconds.
I don't understand why there are these differences, how do I make it always play a sound (foreground, background, not running) and how do I make sure the sound is not cut off the second time the notification is shown?

Answer (score 0):

When notifications are received whilst the app is running the notifications are normally silenced so that the app can handle them in a more native way.

If I remember rightly, receiving the notification will call:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler:
    @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    if someCondition {
        completionHandler(.alert)
    } else {
        completionHandler(.init(rawValue: 0))
    }
}
```

This method is called when the notification is received and if the app is running in the foreground, it will normally be silenced. The completion handler determines what action should be taken and whether or not a notification should show or a sound made etc.

In this case if someCondition is true then it should show the notification natively as it normally would, otherwise dont do anything.

Try calling `completionHandler(.alert)` in this method in your app and your notifications should show

Checkout the [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter)

Comment: Sorry but did you read the documentation link at all? It doesn't specify remote notifications. It's the UserNotifications SDK that was introduced back in iOS 10 and this delegate method does state as its description: "Asks the delegate how to handle a notification that arrived while the app was running in the foreground."

Comment: This [link/tutorial](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/local-notifications-with-ios-10/) also explains the same thing, specifically form a Local notifications perspective

Comment: You specified remote notifications ("When notifications are received"). So I assumed you were talking about push/remote notifications. Your delegate method is already in place, and it calls the completionhandler. Otherwise the notification would simply not show at all. But like I said in the post and in my comment, the problem is with sound, specifically differences in how sound seems to work in foreground/background. I don't see how this answers that question even a little bit. Yes I read the documentation, it didn't help so now I'm here.

Comment: Ok i see how that could cause confusion but to the SDK a notification is just that, doesn't matter whether its remote or local. The key part I was trying to point out in my answer and the comments was that this delegate method is called when the app is in the foreground and by default, the notification itself is normally silenced when your app is in the foreground. so in this method you could return `completionHandler([.alert, .sound])` which might solve your issue.